# MS Acess: How to open form depending on field in subform

Tags: ms-access, subform

I have a Table table_clients and a connected table (1-->many) table_invoices.

I have two forms:

form1(table_clients): all clients with subform1(table_invoices): all invoices for every client

the form2 and subform2 are the same, just objects are placed differently on page.

I want when I have opened a record on form1/subform1, to be able to click a button and open form2/subform2 filtered by the invoice_id and the client_id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following to open the sub form, set the filter on and then specify the filter.

```
Private Sub cmdOpenSubForm_Click()
  DoCmd.OpenForm "table_clients"
  Forms!table_invoices.FilterOn = True
  Forms!table_invoices.Filter = "client_id = " & [txtClientID].value
End Sub
```

Also, if the sub form is open when the record change on the main form you may want to reapply the filter on the sub from and then refresh.  This would be done in the `On Current` event of the main form:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  On Error Resume Next
  Forms!table_invoices.Filter = "client_id = " & [txtClientID].value
  Forms!table_invoices.Refresh
End Sub
```

In the above example you have to have a button with the name `cmdOpenSubForm`.  The sub form must be named `table_invoices`.  The button must reside on the `table_clients` form.  The On Current code should be on the `table_clients` form.  The `invoice_id` and `client_id` are assumed to be numeric.  The `table_clients` form contains a text field named `txtClientID`.  It is assumed that the `txtClientID` field references the primary key for `table_clients` and the `client_id` field in `table_invoices` is the corresponding foreign key.

If you were to click on the `cmdOpenSubForm` button what would result is:

- The `table_invoices` form would be opened
- The `table_invoices` would be filtered to show all invoice records
  for the `client_id` that is currently present in the `table_clients`
  form

If you want to limit the invoice records further than add the to the filter.

Comment: Hi, I get a Runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Also, client_id is on the parent form of invoice_id. Shouldn't it be stated somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer.  I had an error there should have been an `!` in-between Forms and table_invoice instead of the `.`  I also added a better explanation.  hopefully it helps.